# mysql workbench на ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, gtk, warning, mysql-workbench

Пытаюсь запустить mysql workbench на ubuntu 16.04 под sudo юзером:

```
sudo mysql-workbench
```

Выдает:

> (mysql-workbench-bin:964) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Впервые на линуксе, могу не знать каких-то очевидных для линуксоидов вещей.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: запускаете на компьютере или удаленно на сервере?

Comment: удаленно на сервере

Comment: X сервер не проброшен, при подключении укажите параметр икс, например ssh -X user@host , так же проверьте на каком дисплее будет отображение DISPLAY=:0

Comment: На самом деле нужно на сервере программы запускать? Обычная практика - это "прокинуть" порт через ssh к mysql на сервере. Чуть хуже решение, но тоже рабочее, это открыть доступ из вне к нужной базе данных, а у себя работать локально.

Comment: На самое деле нет. Просто я думал это самый простой способ. Было бы здорово работать в mysql-workbench на моем компьютере с виндой, подключившись удаленно к серверу, просто я не знаю как "прокинуть порт" и т.п. Есть ли какой-нибудь пошаговый мануал?

Comment: http://mithrandir.ru/professional/soft-and-hardware/mysql-workbench-server.html читать с "Через SSH туннель"

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, запуск mysql-workbench от root'а — это не самая светлая идея. Скорей всего решается какая-то другая проблема, а решение выбрано не лучшее.

Если всё же нужно запустить X'овое приложение от root'а, то скорей всего проблема в том, что пользователям отличным от того, что запустил X сервер доступ к оному запрещён, а X сессия не передаётся.

Чтобы на один раз исправить можно разрешить доступ к X'ам всем локальным пользователям:

```
xhost +local:
```

Более корректным было бы добавить(раскоментировать) в /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults env_keep += "XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
```

В результате целевой пользователь sudo будет использовать ту же сессия, что и вызывающий.

Редактирование этого файла нетривиально, смотри `sudoedit`.

Comment: В чём проблема от рута запустить при разработке доверенное приложение? Не правильно подходит, это да. Обычно подключение к mysql прокидывают через ssh, а программу запускают у себя.

Comment: отредактировал sudoers указаной строкой, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Igor, просто нет ни каких причин запускать его от root'а... да и где-то за ухом паранойя тихонько шепчет «mysql-workbench недостаточно доверенное приложение»

Comment: @Rooten, не обращай внимания, я не в ту сторону послал копать... просто не думал, что можно умудриться запускать его на удалённом хосте...